# I want to keep image ratio using android daimajia sliderLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want Image Slide in my Android app.
So, I using daimajia library.(https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider)

I have to keep my image's ratio like this.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/main_function01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@mipmap/img_app_function_02" />
```

But, When I use daimajia library's SliderLayout, it doens't work.

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
android:id="@+id/slider"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
custom:auto_cycle="true"
custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />
```

how can i do? or is there any other best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set it per image while adding to the slider:

```
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(context);
        textSliderView
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop)
                .image(url);

        mSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
```

It can be Fit, CenterCrop or CenterInside:

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/daimajia/slider/library/SliderTypes/BaseSliderView.java#L235